# Is anyone familiar with this 29 pin connection?

Tags: power-supply, identification, connector, cables, pinout

It is the output port of a power supply. Anyone knows what this connection is called and where to buy the right cables? If you've come across this, please offer some details. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: There is "Elcon" or something engraved on the connector, along with the logo (not very visible on the photo. Start from there?

Comment: Looks like it's designed for a module that plugs into a chassis, you might not get cables that plug into it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a [TE ELCON 164820x-1](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Tyco%20Electonics%20AMP%20PDFs/Power%20Conn,Cable_Mounted_Cat.pdf) socket where x is 6, 7, or 8 and denotes the size of the power contacts (12, 16, or 12 and 16, respectively).